# Troubleshooting vue extends failure

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, mixins

I have a pretty simple mixin that doesn't seem to be working using nuxt.  It's so basic I'm at my whits end trying to figure out the bug. My component is part of a fairly complicated form composition scheme, but the mixin is super simple.

script from my component simplified

```js
import { VInput } from 'vuetify'
import FieldMask from '~/utils/FieldMask'
import CognitoField from '~/mixins/cognitoField'
export default {
  name: 'CognitoBaseField',
  extends: [VInput, CognitoField],
  props: {
    inlineLabels: { default: true },
    noIndependantSubmission: Boolean,
    groupEdit: false,
    cognitoName: '',
    displayValue: '',
    fieldValue: '',
    placeHolder: { defalut: 'enter text' },
    label: '',
    masker: { type: Function, default: FieldMask },
    items: [],
    selected: {},
    itemText: '',
    itemValue: '',
    showForm: Boolean,
    disableEnterKeySubmission: Boolean,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
      formActive: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onCancelClick() {
      this.value = ''
      this.formActive = false
      console.log('test mixin')
      console.log(this.thisIsATest())
    },
  },
}
```

My mixin - verbatim

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    testComp() {
      return 'working'
    },
  },
  methods: {
    thisIsATest() {
      return 'working'
    },
  },
}
```

The result here is I trigger `onCancelClick` on the component and the page crashes with

```
TypeError: this.thisIsATest is not a function
```

To really include a usable version of the component in this question I'd need to share a number of components so its probably not called for.  Unless somebody can obviously see a glaring error, I guess the real question is how to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Did you imported the mixin in your component?

Comment: Like `mixins: [CognitoField]` in your `export default { ...`.

Comment: @kissu - does `mixins` go inside the mixin?  In the component (shown above) line 3 is the mxin import and line 6 is the `extends` list.
`

Comment: If you want to use a mixin, you need to import it and to tell that you want to use it thanks to `mixins`. As shown in [the documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#mixins). I've never used `inherits` neither saw it used anywhere tbh. Try mixins as I've suggested above, should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```html
<script>
import CognitoField from '~/mixins/cognitoField'

export default {
  name: 'CognitoBaseField',
  mixins: [CognitoField],
}
</script>
```

Regarding the documentation, this pattern is no [longer recommended](https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#mixins). The usage of [Composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) is better on several aspects.

Comment: I'm confused.  How is this answer different from the code I posted in my question?

Comment: Oh, snap, I just saw it.  I used extends instead of mixins (so dumb).  Also, I believe composition is only for vue3.  I'm using vue2.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JamieMarshall composition API can be used with Vue2 too: https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api